# How can I create a view that contains the historical average salary for every department?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

This are the UML tables we are working with:[UML tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html)

I recently started working with MySQL so I'm a bit lost. I tried this part and this is the code I could get but it gives me an error:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS historical_average; -- this way we won't have any problems duplicating views

CREATE VIEW hist_avg_salary AS -- naming the view
select dep.dept_name as DepartmentName, avg(salary) as AVG_Salary
from departments as dep
natural join salaries 
group by dep.dept_name
order by avg(salary) desc;
# now working with the VIEW
SELECT * FROM hist_avg_salary;
SHOW FULL TABLES IN employees WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';
```

How can I fixed it so it works? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please share error you got. For me order by avg(salary) desc; in the view looks very suspicious

Comment: Well, now the program runs but I do not get the correct average values.

Comment: Some sample data and desired output will help us to help you

Comment: I'm not able to post pictures so I'll add a link to the correct result and to my output.
https://imgur.com/a/tgXLHMD

Answer (score 0):

You should use alias of the column for order by :

```
order by AVG_Salary desc;
```